# Accessing a variable outside of class

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have two classes built of constructor method. Can I access the variables of those classes by defining a function outside? Example:

```
class MyCat1():
    def __init__(self, weight1, speed1):
    self.weight1 = ...
    self.speed1 = ...

class MyCat2():
    def __init__(self, weight2, speed2):
    self.weight2 = ...
    self.speed2 = ...

def run(self, weight1, weight2, speed1, speed2):
    self.sum = weight1.speed1+ weight2.speed2
    x = self.sum
    return x
```

Comment: No, you access *instance attributes* via *an instance of the class*. What exactly are you actually trying to do?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but there's not much point in writing two individual classes that are identical except for attribute names. Why not have a single `MyCat` class that has `weight` and `speed` attributes, no numbers required? You can make more than one instance of a single class, of course.

Comment: That's just an example. My question is can I define two classes for two separate objects and define a function which will have attributes from both classes and that is outside of both classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is closer to what you're shooting for. You just need to define your `class` one time, then you can make as many instances of it as you'd like.

```
class MyCat():
    def __init__(self, weight, speed):
        self.weight = weight
        self.speed = speed
```

This is a free function, and therefore has no `self`, so you can just pass in instances of `MyCat` to work with. You can call the attributes `weight` and `speed` off the instances.

```
def run(cat1, cat2):
    return cat1.weight * cat1.speed + cat2.weight * cat2.speed
```

For example

```
>>> cat1 = MyCat(5, 10)
>>> cat2 = MyCat(3, 5)
>>> run(cat1, cat2)
65
```

Answer (score 3):

I would make a single Cat class and keep the method in the class and pass the instances to the method:

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, weight, speed):
        self.weight = weight
        self.speed = speed

    def run(self,other):
        return self.weight * other.weight + self.speed * other.speed

cat1 = Cat(2, 2)
cat2 = Cat(3, 3)

print(cat1.run(cat2))
12
```

There is no point creating pretty much identical classes and it would get quite arduous if you decide to have 100 cats.